# reddit 503 service unavailable

Tags: reddit, failed-installation

Has anyone installed their own version of Reddit?

I'm using Oracle VM Virtual Box and have installed recommended 12.04 (Precise Pangolin) Ubuntu.

I then ran the reddit install script for Ubuntu and it seemed to run ok and all of Reddit was installed.

I then updated /etc/hosts and added: 127.0.0.1   reddit.local

Now when inputting http://reddit.local/ in the webbrowser I get the error:
503 Service Unavailable
No server is available to handle this request.

Any ideas here would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you run `sudo reddit-start` in the VM?  Also, does running `sudo reddit-shell` work?